# Incorrect Syntax near ' '.C#

Tags: c#, syntax, sql-server-express

I get error

> INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR ' '

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection=conn;
cmd.CommandText = "update student set Name='" + textBox1.Text + "',Family='" + textBox2.Text + "',Fathername='" + textBox3.Text + "',ShenasName='" + textBox4.Text + "',CodeMeli'" + textBox5.Text + "',Tavalod'" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "',Address'" + richTextBox1.Text + "',Madraak'" + textBox7.Text + "',Shahriye'" + textBox8.Text + "',Mobile'" + textBox6.Text + "'where Name=" + textBox1.Text;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

My database is SQL Server Express.

Comment: Starting with the field codeMeli you are missing the equal sign after the fields in your commandText. Just have a look how the assembled CommandText looks like at the moment.

Comment: As a side note: 1) Use parameterized queries instead of building a query string including parameters. This makes the code easier to read and avoids SQL injection. 2) This suffers from SQL injection. You could apply escaping to the parameters to avoid this problem, but parameterized queries are still preferable.

Comment: That and the `where Name=" + textBox1.Text;` should be `where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "'";` SQL Server expects alphanumeric values to be quoted. Also, please use parameterized queries. Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: check my solution and tell me if something is not clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors:

- missing equals after: `CodeMeli=`, `Tavalod=`, `Address=`, `Madraak=`, `Shahriye=`, `Mobile=`
- missing ending of the sql statement `+ "'"`

This will work:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "update student set Name='" + textBox1.Text + "',Family='" + textBox2.Text + "',Fathername='" + textBox3.Text + "',ShenasName='" + textBox4.Text + "',CodeMeli='" + textBox5.Text + "',Tavalod='" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "',Address='" + richTextBox1.Text + "',Madraak='" + textBox7.Text + "',Shahriye='" + textBox8.Text + "',Mobile='" + textBox6.Text + "'where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

In any case, I recommend you the use of Parameters. [Why?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Student SET Name=@Name, Family=@Family, Fathername=@Fathername, ShenasName=@ShenasName, CodeMeli = @CodeMeli,Tavalod=@Tavalod, Address=@Address, Madraak=@Madraak, Shahriye=@Madraak, Mobile=@Mobile WHERE Name=@Name";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fathername", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShenasName", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeMeli", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tavalod", maskedTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Madraak", textBox7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shahriye", textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", textBox6.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

using `table2` instead of `student`

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "update table2 set Name='" + textBox1.Text + "',Family='" + textBox2.Text + "',Fathername='" + textBox3.Text + "',ShenasName='" + textBox4.Text + "',CodeMeli='" + textBox5.Text + "',Tavalod='" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "',Address='" + richTextBox1.Text + "',Madraak='" + textBox7.Text + "',Shahriye='" + textBox8.Text + "',Mobile='" + textBox6.Text + "'where Name='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

OR

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE table2 SET Name=@Name, Family=@Family, Fathername=@Fathername, ShenasName=@ShenasName, CodeMeli = @CodeMeli,Tavalod=@Tavalod, Address=@Address, Madraak=@Madraak, Shahriye=@Madraak, Mobile=@Mobile WHERE Name=@Name";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fathername", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShenasName", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeMeli", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tavalod", maskedTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Madraak", textBox7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shahriye", textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", textBox6.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

Comment: i use your solution but get another error, Invaild Object Name student

Comment: check the sqlconnection datasource. I updated the AttachDbFilename.
Does your database have a table called "student"?

Comment: my database have a table call Table2 . where i can change student to table2?? help me. thanks for answer

Comment: Check now, I added both solutions with student or table2. Also check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337520.aspx You might want to change the name of the table

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection=conn;

cmd.CommandText = @"
UPDATE 
   Student 
SET 
   Name=@Name, Family=@Family, Fathername=@Fathername, ShenasName=@ShenasName, CodeMeli = @CodeMeli,
   Tavalod=@Tavalod, Address=@Address, Madraak=@Madraak, Shahriye=@Madraak, Mobile=@Mobile
WHERE
   Name=@Name";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fathername", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShenasName", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeMeli", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tavalod", maskedTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Madraak", textBox7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shahriye", textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", textBox6.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();               

MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

Here is the code. First Format your query properly, your query was unreadable. Second use Command parameters to avoid SQL Injection. You can read in Wikipedia about sql injection. Third write "nice" textBox ID, which have some meaning.

Comment: i use your solution but i get another error,  Inavaild Object Name Student.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `CommandText`. There are some Parameters without ( = )
Format like this :

```
cmd.CommandText = "update student set Name='" + textBox1.Text + "',
                                    Family='" + textBox2.Text + "',
                                    Fathername='" + textBox3.Text + "',
                                    ShenasName='" + textBox4.Text + "',
                                    CodeMeli='" + textBox5.Text + "',
                                    Tavalod='" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "',
                                    Address='" + richTextBox1.Text + "',
                                    Madraak='" + textBox7.Text + "',
                                    Shahriye='" + textBox8.Text + "',
                                    Mobile='" + textBox6.Text + "'
                   where Name=" + textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax `')'`

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers(Id,Name,Country,) values (@Id,@Name,@Country)",con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
      MessageBox.Show("Added successfully!");
 }
```

Comment: This needs more of an explanation as to what it is you are changing.  Showing a code block is great, but simply saying "incorect syntax ')'" does very little to explain what is wrong.

Comment: This should focus on what the line(s) with the incorrect syntax are and explain why it causes the failure to occur.